# cufon is not a function

Tags: jquery

Offff dont understand why I get cufon.font is not a function error. I followed all the instructions at its website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Futura_Lt_BT_400.font.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{

    Cufon.replace('.starter .content');
    }

            <div class="starter">
                <div class="image-1">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="content">Family guy funny show.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image-2">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="content">Family guy funny show.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
                <!-- <img src="images/logo_fg.png" alt="Logo" class="logo" /> -->
            </div>
```

Website is at http://www.pangeaadvisors.org/IDC/

Any suggestion appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not in your main page, it's in `Futura_Lt_BT_400.font.js`.

The line starts with:

```
Cufon.FuturaLightFont({"w":207,"face":{"font-family":"Futura Lt BT" ...
```

Normally, these JS files start with `Cufon.registerFont`.  Where did this JS file come from?  Did you use the [Font Generator](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) from the Cufon website?

Update: The inline JS is also malformed.  It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    Cufon.replace('.starter .content');
});
```

Note the extra `);` on the last line.

Comment: Hi, yes I used cufon's font generator?

Comment: The default script that comes out of the generator looks different from what's in your JS file.  What options did you change?

Comment: nothing. I selected  The EULAs of these fonts allow Web Embedding (without Adobe Flash) and  I acknowledge and accept these terms. I left other sections as they are.

Comment: What's in the "Customization" box, near the bottom, just above the terms?  Does it say `Cufon.registerFont`?

Comment: Then we seem to be at an impasse.  Humour me - replace the text `Cufon.FuturaLightFont` in the file `js/Futura_Lt_BT_400.font.js` with the text `Cufon.registerFont`, then tell me what happens.

Comment: same error. you can see it yourself at the website link I provided in the original message.

Comment: Yes, I can see the same error, and I can see that the contents of that file have **not** changed.  It still starts with `Cufon.FuturaLightFont`.  Did you update that file on the server?

Comment: Never mind, I see what happened, the *name* of the file was changed.  It is what's *inside* that file that needs to be changed.

Comment: my bad, I misunderstood your earlier message. Let me try again.